# How can WPF RIchtextbox display Unicode?

Tags: wpf, unicode, richtextbox

I use the WPF RichTexBox control in WPF project. The problem I get stuck in is it cannot display the unicode as the System.Windows.Forms.RichTextbox in Win Project.

E.g : When I copy a paragraph of Chinese language and paste it to the WPF Richtextbox. The font is break and it cannot display. But when I use System.Windows.Forms.RichTextbox control then I display ok.

So, how can I resolve this problem in WPF project.

Comment: When I paste some Chinese text from Wikipedia it works just fine.

Comment: Can you please provide a specific example / paragraph that isn't working? When I test this using any language on translate.google.com it functions fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you're using a font that doesn't support Unicode.  Try making sure you're using a Unicode-capable font to display the Chinese characters.  (If you don't know, try a few common fonts, like Tahoma, in wordpad.)